# DFA which accepts either even number of 1s or odd number of 0s. ex- 0,11,10,01,110,011,000,101 etc

Tags: dfa

DFA which accepts either even number of 1s or odd number of 0s. ex- 0,11,10,01,110,011,000,101 etc

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: I am trying to draw dfa for this but unable. that's why asking

Answer (score 2):

we can make four different cases that are 
[image: the transition table is given as]

and corresponding the table we will have three final states that are acceptable cases. let the states be:

1. q0 for even even
2. q1 for odd even
3. q2 for even odd
4. and q3 for odd odd

so the transition graph would be given by

[image: the transition graph is given by]

Answer (score 1):

i think below DFA will full fill requirements...i made in paint so,not looking pretty.[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
            State           O               1
           ->q0*            q1              q2
             q1*            q0              q3
             q2             q3              q0
             q3*            q2              q1
```

q0 is the initial state and q0,q1,q3 are the final states.

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 states like below

```
      +-------------+
      |  0s  |  1s  |
+-------------------+
| q0* | even | even |
+-------------------+
| q1  | even | odd  |
+-------------------+
| q2* | odd  | even |
+-------------------+
| q3* | odd  | odd  |
+-------------------+
```

See that your accepting states are q0, q2 and q3

Your state transition table will be like this

```
      +----+----+
      | 0  | 1  |
+---------------+
| q0* | q2 | q1 |
+---------------+
| q1  | q3 | q0 |
+---------------+
| q2* | q0 | q3 |
+---------------+
| q3* | q1 | q4 |
+-----+----+----+
```